# R How to plot "samples" on the right and "variables" on the top in gplots heatmap2?

Tags: r, rotation, heatmap

By using the command:

```
heatmap.2(exp, col = greenred(100), scale="none", ColSideColors = Carcolors, 
    # dendrogram = "row",
    key=T, symkey=FALSE, density.info="none", trace="none", cexRow=1, cexCol=0.9)
```

The heatmap2 plots "samples" as columns and variables as rows. How can I rotate the heatmap counterclock wise 90 degree so the sample names are listed on the right and variables are listed on the top (with RowSideColors on the right also)? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you right, but does a tranpose of your matrix do the job?

Here is an example:

```
 require(gplots)
data(mtcars)
x  <- as.matrix(mtcars)
heatmap.2(x)
```

[image]

```
# transpose the matrix
heatmap.2(t(x))
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Two other options, of course, would be to turn either (a) your monitor or (b) your head, 90 degrees.

Comment: Also possible:  xrandr -o left ;)

Comment: "Transpose" did not work properly when I tried before - color was off and dendrograms and color key did not show up. Tried it again after seeing your post. It actually worked. So strange. Thanks!